# How to automatically reorder a class into empty and non-empty methods in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, overriding

It happens quite often, when implementing a big interface, that I only implement a handful of methods, while the rest remains completely untouched. This leads to the code being scattered over a very large files.

What I do is to manually move the implemented methods to the top of the class, and surrounding the empty methods with a `//region Unimplemented Overrides`. This can get a little bit tedious, because the implemented methods are scattered among hundreds of empty methods. I was wondering if there is any way I can do this, or something similar to it, automatically with IntelliJ IDEA 15.

Comment: I am not sure if I clearly understand your question, but maybe the Rearranger plugin ( http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/173 ) can help you.

Comment: The code solution is to create an Adapter class that implements the interface and provides empty implementations of all the methods. Then have your class extend that adapter class. Then you only have to override the ones you want.